# Porting network auditing software to Windows

Tags: c, windows, network-programming, mingw, porting

I am attempting to port a network auditing program called Argus to Windows using gnulib. It is my first time using gnulib, or porting software at all for that matter, and I've gotten stuck because the source code for Argus does not contain a Makefile.am which gnulib seems to need (the configure.ac is available, though). Is it possible to continue without an automake file? Is gnulib even the best option for this? What alternatives do I have? I have very little experience with this so any guidance on the matter is appreciated.

Thanks!